# How to make an array linkable that's using implode?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My array displays properly but I would like for the link inside to display the current value of the array.

Here is my code:

```
foreach( $persons as $pid => $p)
{
    echo '<a href="?tag=">' . implode( '</a>, <a href="?tag=">', $tags[ $p['id'] ])  . '</a>';
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

This is what I want to display:

```
<a href="?tag=tag1">tag1</a>, <a href="?tag=tag2">tag2</a>
```

---

**UPDATE**
I got the answer elsewhere. Turns out it was pretty simple. Going to accept answer that's helped me improve on my code.

```
$tags_arr = $tags[$p['id']];    
    foreach($tags_arr as $v){
  $out[] = "<a href='?tag=$v'>$v</a>";
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the example contents of both `$persons` and `$tags`?

Comment: What's wrong with another foreach?

Comment: @michael I've added more content please let me know if you need anything else or if it's possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @checkenginelight Please post `var_dump($persons)`  and `var_dump($tags)` from just before you begin your `echo` statements.

Comment: @checkenginelight See some changes in my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `$tags` is an array itself, and you are attempting to write out each tag for each `$p['id']`. If I have it correct, don't use `implode()` for this.  Instead use two foreach loops.

```
foreach ($persons as $pid => $p) {
  foreach ($tags as $t) {
    echo "<a href='?tag={$t[$p['id']]}'>{$t[$p['id']]}</a>\n";
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I see some problems here:

```
    $persons[$row['id']]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $persons[$row['id']]['height'] = $row['height'];
    $persons[ $row['id'] ] = array( 'id' => $row['id'], 'tag' => $row['tag']);
```

Above, you set the `title` and `height` array keys to `$persons[$row['id']]`.  Following that though, you overwrite the whole `$persons[$row['id']]` with a new `array()`.  Instead since you're keeping the same array keys you can simply use:

```
$persons[$row['id']] = $row;
```

Now where I believe the most serious problem is:

```
$tags[ $row['id'] ][] = $row['tag'];
```

By using the `[]` notation, you are appending `$row['tag']` onto the `$tags[ $row['id']` *as an array element* rather than setting its value to the tag.  That's the reason you're getting `Array(1)` in place of the tag value.  Instead use:

```
$tags[$row['id']] = $row['tag'];
```

Comment: I did have it like this before but it caused an issue for separation. That's why I used implode to add a comma.

Comment: The first part worked like a charm. When I switch the tags I get an error `implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in` and the foreach doesn't work either.

Comment: if I do a var_dump on $tags I get this
array(1) { [2291]=> string(9) "landscape" }

Comment: @checkenginelight Please post your whole code as you currently have it. We're off track with `$tags`. Your original code implies `$tags` is supposed to hold many per person but you have no query to gather them.  The other SQL fetch has only one tag per.

Comment: np i've added my query. The above var_dump was for if you take the [] off and display it like this: `$tags[$row['id']] = $row['tag'];` per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

use http_build_query — Generate URL-encoded query string

SYNTAX : string http_build_query ( mixed $query_data [, string $numeric_prefix [, string $arg_separator [, int $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738 ]]] )

Returns a URL-encoded string.

```
<?php
    $data = array('foo'=>'bar',
                  'baz'=>'boom',
                  'cow'=>'milk',
                  'php'=>'hypertext processor');

    echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
    echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');

    ?>
```

The above example will output:

foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor

foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor